# Please help - ORA-00917: missing comma insert error

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
create table gradinita333333 
(
    cod_Copil     number not null,
    cod_Parinti   number not null,
    nume_T        varchar2(25) ,
    nume_M        varchar2(25) ,
    prenume_M     varchar2(25) ,
    prenume_T     varchar2(25) ,
    nume_C        varchar2(25),
    data_nasterii date,
    adresa        varchar2(100),
    Grupa         number(5)
)

INSERT INTO gradinita333333 (cod_Copil, cod_Parinti, nume_T, nume_M, prenume_M, prenume_T, nume_C, data_nasterii, adresa, Grupa) 
VALUES ('1114', '4312', 'Bogdan','Randulescu','Ioana','Randulescu','Victor', 'TO_DATE('17/02/1995', dd/mm/yyyy','StrStefanCelMic','1'));
```

Comment: I don't know PL\SQL, but I'm pretty confident that functions (like `TO_DATE`) aren't supposed to be within single quotes (which are used to define literal strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A missing statement terminator for `create table`, as well as invalid usage of `to_date` along with a superfluous closing bracket for `insert` lead to various errors. When fixed, it *works*:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE gradinita333333(
  2    cod_copil      NUMBER NOT NULL,
  3    cod_parinti    NUMBER NOT NULL,
  4    nume_t         VARCHAR2(25),
  5    nume_m         VARCHAR2(25),
  6    prenume_m      VARCHAR2(25),
  7    prenume_t      VARCHAR2(25),
  8    nume_c         VARCHAR2(25),
  9    data_nasterii  DATE,
 10    adresa         VARCHAR2(100),
 11    grupa          NUMBER(5)
 12  );

Table created.
```

---

```
SQL> INSERT INTO gradinita333333(
  2      cod_copil,
  3      cod_parinti,
  4      nume_t,
  5      nume_m,
  6      prenume_m,
  7      prenume_t,
  8      nume_c,
  9      data_nasterii,
 10      adresa,
 11      grupa
 12    )VALUES(
 13      '1114',
 14      '4312',
 15      'Bogdan',
 16      'Randulescu',
 17      'Ioana',
 18      'Randulescu',
 19      'Victor',
 20      to_date('17/02/1995 ', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
 21      'StrStefanCelMic',
 22      '1'
 23    );

1 row created.

SQL>
```